# SQL - Returning all fields that hold a sequence of unknown digits

Tags: sql

I want to return all the fields within the database that hold a sequence of 16 digits.

Something like:

```
Select * From Table 
Where Column_1 LIKE '%----------------%' (where all - are numbers)
```

is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Also provide sample data and desired results.  Are you looking for a field that contains 16 numbers anywhere in the string or that contains exactly 16 numbers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "16 numbers" ~ "16 digits"

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu . . . "contain" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this way.

```
Select * From Table 
Where LEN(Column_1) = 16
```

For Numeric only you can add this too.

```
Select * From Table 
Where LEN(Column_1) = 16 AND ISNUMERIC(Column_1) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

according to standard SQl you can specify a set of character using square bracket ([]).  In your case the solution wolud be

```
Select * From Table 
Where Column_1 LIKE '[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]
      [1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]'
```

Using that code you specify that there are 16 time a character included in 1- 9 interval, substantially (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 or 9), that was given repeating 16 times the expression [1-9].  hope this help